# How to exit when assertion fails in python?

Tags: python

I would like to use assertions, so that my script exists, when assertions fail.

For that I wrote an own function, which stops the script

```
def assertExit(mlambda, errorMessage):
    res = mlambda()
    if res != True:
        sys.exit(errorMessage)

assertExit((lambda: False), "Should fail")
```

Is there a way to do that with pythons native assertions?

```
assert False # should exit the script
```

Comment: Native assertions will raise an exception if they fail, which will terminate the application unless you catch it.

Comment: Simply *not catching* `AssertionError`s should do the trick… why do you need an even more direct `exit`?

Comment: you are right, failed assertions do stop the script already. I was confused, because the logs order was wrong, and in the logs, after assertion exception, some output was logged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been pointed out, an unhandled `AssertionError`, as thrown by `assert`, should already stop your script.

`assert` always fails if the condition being tested doesn't evaluate to `True`. That is [as long as you do not run python with optimizations enabled (`-O` flag)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assert), in which case it will not throw an `AssertionError` (as `assert` statements are skipped in `optimized` mode).

So

```
def assert_exit(condition, err_message):
    try:
        assert condition
    except AssertionError:
        sys.exit(err_message)
```

Should be what you want, if you absolutely want to call `sys.exit()` and use `assert`; However this

```
assert condition
```

will stop your script just as fine and provide a `stacktrace`, which saves you the trouble of entering a custom error message each time you call `assert_exit`, and points you directly to the offending party.